# Change the size of C++ vector without initializing added elements

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

In my program there is some frequently used data type with trivial fields

```cpp
struct Element {
  Element() noexcept : x( 0 ), y( 0 ), z( 0 ) {}
  float x, y, z;
};
```

and also there are many pieces of code taking vectors of `Element`s, e.g.

```cpp
void foo( std::vector<Element> & es );
```

So it would be very complicated to introduce radical changes in `Element` (like changing its default constructor) or rewriting all these pieces to replace `std::vector` with something else.

And I have some performance-critical place where a vector of `Element`s must be created, filled and passed to `foo`:

```cpp
std::vector<Element> es;
// resize is necessary only to allocate the storage, all values will be rewritten in the parallel region later
es.resize( N );
// perform computation of all values in the vector in parallel for best performance
tbb::parallel_for( tbb::blocked_range<size_t>( 0, es.size() ), 
    [&]( const tbb::blocked_range<size_t> & range ) {
        for ( size_t i = range.begin(); i < range.end(); ++i ) {
           ...
           es[i] = ...
        }
    }
…
foo( es );
```

What I observe is that `es.resize` takes considerable time for huge `N` because it not only allocates the memory, but also default initializes every element, which is not necessary in my case.

Is there a way to increase the size of the vector without initializing its elements, which will be all initialized later? Something like `std::make_unique_for_overwrite` available for unique_ptrs.

Comment: You want `reserve`, but to use that you have to add elements into the vector using `push_back` or similar functions.

Comment: It's a rare case, when it's better to use a raw array in `std::unique_ptr<Element[]>`. FYI `std::string` in C++23 gets [`std::string::resize_and_overwrite()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize_and_overwrite) for such purposes. IDK why `std::vector<T>` does not.

Comment: You could potentially add a tag c'tor that is a no-op. Then reserve + emplace_back in a loop, hoping an optimising compiler sees the whole thing as discardable. Might be a long shot, though.

Comment: @NathanOliver `emplace_back()` would be the preferred choice

Comment: Another option is to just get rid of the `vector`. Since you know exactly how many elements you need memory for, allocate a byte array of that size, and then use `placement-new` or `std::construct_at()` to construct the actual elements in it where needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You can't use `emplace_back` with the OP's type as is: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1aec8b768427b696.  If you use `emplace_back({1, 2, 3})` instead it will work but `push_back` will do the same thing.

Comment: @NathanOliver you can if a suitable constructor is added to the struct.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment by StoryTeller, the following solution worked for me.

I added no-op constructor in Element:

```
struct NoInit {};
inline constexpr NoInit noInit;

struct Element {
  Element() noexcept : x( 0 ), y( 0 ), z( 0 ) {}
  Element( NoInit ) noexcept { }
  float x, y, z;
};
```

Then replaced `es.resize( N );` with the call to new function:

```
template<class V>
void resizeNoInit( V & v, size_t targetSize )
{
    // allocate enough memory
    v.reserve( targetSize );
    // resize without memory access
    while ( v.size() < targetSize )
        v.emplace_back( noInit );
    // in case initial size was larger
    v.resize( targetSize );
}
```

making initial `reserve` and then adding elements in the vector one by one using `emplace_back` without actual access to the element's memory.

It works many times faster than standard `vector::resize`, and Clang is especially good in optimizing it:

```
resizeNoInit: 0.0011801
std. resize:  0.0184119
```

Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/n6Tc7dj88

Comment: The timings change if you repeat the test and take the average time (rather than running each only once). Then Clang is pretty similar and GCC's resize is faster than resizeNoInit. Also, in your test, you should use the same constructor, so call resize(N, noInit). See https://godbolt.org/z/Yn7G1nz9M

Comment: @flipchart, thanks. Please note that `es.resize(N, noInit)` creates one element using `noInit` constructor and then copies it to initialize all other elements in the vector. Surprisingly, compilers can optimize it well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that a custom allocator can help you. The 2nd template parameter of the `std::vector` can be used for this purpose.

And that allows you to implement the best fitting solution for you.

If you want that the values are not initialized, then you could derive your custom allocator from `std::allocator` and overwrite/add a new `construct` function. The explanation for `construct` can be read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct).

If we copy and paste the functions prototype from the above link, but implement it as an "empty" function, then we can maybe get what you want.

And, please use the `std::vector`s `reserve` function (omitted in below example).

Please see a very simple example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Element {
    Element() noexcept : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}
    double x, y, z;
};

template <class T>
struct MyAllocator : public std::allocator<T> {
    template <class U, class... Args> void construct(U*, Args&&...) {}
};
using ElementAllocator = MyAllocator<Element>;

int main() {
    std::vector<Element, ElementAllocator> data(5, Element{});

    for (const Element& e : data) std::cout << e.x << '\t' << e.y << '\t' << e.z << '\n';
    data.resize(10);
    for (const Element& e : data) std::cout << e.x << '\t' << e.y << '\t' << e.z << '\n';
}
```

Most probably you would need to write an allocator function that will exactly fit your needs. I do not have enough information here for more support . . .

Comment: Thanks. As far as I understand, this will require to change `std::vector<Element>` to `std::vector<Element, ElementAllocator>` both in the place of construction and in all functions receiving and passing that data type, which is a lot of work in big codebase. Also it will require more changes since now all `resize`s stop initializing elements and not only the necessary one.

Comment: It isn't the allocator that does the default-construction but the container itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a C++20-capable union called `ndi_t<>` for types without a destructor to omit their default-construction:

```
#pragma once
#include <type_traits>
#include <new>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
#if defined(__cpp_concepts)
    requires std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>
#endif
union ndi_t
{
    ndi_t();
    template<typename ... Args>
        requires std::is_constructible_v<T, Args &&...>
    ndi_t( Args &&... args );
    ndi_t &operator =( T const &assign );
    template<typename ... Args>
        requires std::is_constructible_v<T, Args &&...>
    T &construct( Args &&... args );
    operator T &();
    T *operator &();
    T *operator ->();
private:
    T m_value;
};

template<typename T>
#if defined(__cpp_concepts)
    requires std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>
#endif
inline ndi_t<T>::ndi_t()
{
}

template<typename T>
#if defined(__cpp_concepts)
    requires std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>
#endif
template<typename ... Args>
#if defined(__cpp_concepts)
    requires std::is_constructible_v<T, Args &&...>
#endif
inline ndi_t<T>::ndi_t( Args &&... args ) :
    m_value( std::forward<Args>( args ) ... )
{
}

template<typename T>
#if defined(__cpp_concepts)
    requires std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>
#endif
inline ndi_t<T> & ndi_t<T>::operator =( T const &assign )
{
    m_value = assign;
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
#if defined(__cpp_concepts)
    requires std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>
#endif
template<typename ... Args>
#if defined(__cpp_concepts)
    requires std::is_constructible_v<T, Args &&...>
#endif
inline T &ndi_t<T>::construct( Args &&... args )
{
    new( (void *)&m_value ) T( std::forward<Args>( args ) ... );
    return m_value;
}

template<typename T>
#if defined(__cpp_concepts)
    requires std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>
#endif
inline ndi_t<T>::operator T &()
{
    return m_value;
}

template<typename T>
#if defined(__cpp_concepts)
    requires std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>
#endif
inline T *ndi_t<T>::operator &()
{
    return &m_value;
}

template<typename T>
#if defined(__cpp_concepts)
    requires std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>
#endif
inline T *ndi_t<T>::operator ->()
{
    return &m_value;
}
```

With that you could f.e. do a `vector<ndi_t<int>>::resize( N )` without the appended items to be default-initialized.
The objects mostly behave like their native-counterparts., i.e. you can assign values of the type encapuslated in ndi_t inside them and you could read their native values. If you want to get the address of the encapsulated object just apply & to the `ndi_t<>`-object and you'll get the address of the encapsulated data. And you can access members with the `->`-operator if the encapsulated type is a class-type.
The only drawaback so far I've seen is that if you have a container and you want to get the address an iterator points to with `to_address( it )` you get the address of the `ndi_t<>`-object and not the encapsulated object; so you have to apply `&*` to the address returned by `to_address()`.